# Spring Flex 1.5.0-M1 in Maven Repo anywhere?

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring, maven, blazeds

I like to move to the latest version of this artifact and Maven central only as 1.3.0-RELEASE.

I can download the entire `spring-flex-dist.zip` but am at a loss as to add the JAR to my Nexus.  Should I just use the pom.xml file that is in the zip distribution (it has a TON of dependencies...and profiles, etc.)?

Better yet, is there another repo somewhere I can get it from?

While we are at it, how about it's dependency BlazeDS 4.x.  Can't find that one anywhere!  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it from `http://s3.amazonaws.com/maven.springframework.org/milestone` repository. Note that the version number is `1.5.0.M1`.

Comment: And the dependent BlazeDS 4.0.0 artifacts can be had from:  http://s3browse.springsource.com/browse/maven.springframework.org/external/com/adobe/blazeds/